# Postgres - calculation being returned as string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In the method below, I do ol.price * ol.committed.  price is a decimal (40.00)

```
  def self.find_for_order(order)
    if order
      select("ol.*, p.name as name, (ol.price * ol.committed) as sku_total, p.price as price, p.style_number AS product_style_number, p.name").
      from("order_lines ol").
      joins("LEFT JOIN skus s ON s.sku_number = ol.style_number").
      joins("LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = s.product_id").
      where("ol.order_id = #{order}").
      group("ol.id, p.price, product_style_number, name, ol.style_number")
    end
  end
```

In my view I have this:

```
number_to_currency(@order_lines.map(&:sku_total).sum)
```

This is the result:

```
$500,400.00
```

If I run inspect on it I get this:

```
["500", "400"]
```

So it thinks they are strings, and just slapping them together instead of adding them.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast the values to numbers.

```
number_to_currency(@order_lines.map{|ol| ol.sku_total.to_f }.sum)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there anything I can do to avoid this?  I'm trying to move from MySql to Postgres, and these types of things make me a bit nervous.

Comment: You could try casting the computed value to double precision in the select clause and see if that helps AR understand the result type more naturally. `select ... (ol.price * ol.committed)::double precision as sku_total, ...`